# To say that the sequence $a_n$ is “bounded above” is to say what?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is a homework question for the coursera course Calculus 2 Sequences and Series offered by Jim Fowler at Ohio State

> To say that the sequence $a_n$ is “bounded above” is to say what?
>
> 1. For all $M\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so that $a_n \ge M$.
> 2. There exists an $M\in \mathbb{R}$, so that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have $a_n \ge M$.
> 3. For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $M\in \mathbb{R}$, so that $a_n \ge M$.
> 4. For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $M\in \mathbb{R}$, so that $a_n \le M$.
> 5. There exists an $M\in \mathbb{R}$, so that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have $a_n \le M$.

I am split between choice number 4 and choice number 5.  I am having trouble determining how these choices are different.  Does choice number 4 suggest that $M$ can be a different number for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Thanks in advance for your help

Edit:
Here is the definition of bounded above given by the text:

> Deﬁnition: A sequence ($a_n$) is bounded above if there is some number
>   $M$ so that for all $n$, we have $a_n \le M$. Likewise, a sequence
>   ($a_n$) is bounded below if there is some number $M$ so that for every
>   $n$, we have $a_n \ge M$. If a sequence is both bounded above and
>   bounded below, the sequence is said to be bounded.

Comment: Think about how 4 holds for any sequence.

Comment: I wonder how he defines 'bounded above' to ask this question.

Comment: Order of quantifiers is important! In choice 4, for each specific $n\in\mathbb{N}$, you get an $M$ (which may depend on $n$) that bounds $a_n$. This statement is completely vacuous.

Comment: Your guess is exactly correct. Choice 4 suggests that there can be a different $M$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$; choice 5 means that there must be a single $M$ that works for every $n\in\Bbb N$. A more careful writer would have phrased #4 as “For *each* $n\in \Bbb N$, there exists…”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 4 is always true: there you can indeed pick a different $M$ for every $n$ (so you can take $M = a_n$). Option 5 is the right one: one $M$ must work for all $n$.

(And, for completeness sake, option 3 is always true as well; option 2 is "bounded below"; option 1 is (equivalent to) the negation of option 5, i.e. "not bounded above").